# How do you get Training Guides?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

I'd like to keep training my Prowler while I'm doing online quests, but even Intense Training is kinda slow. Training Guides seem to speed levelling up considerably, but I'm not sure how I got mine, or where to get more.

Comment: you could set them to just normal training? that lasts indefinitely at a slower rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there are any other sources of this item, but you receive one from an NPC every time one of your palicoes hits level 20.

Comment: Hmm. I can no longer hire Palicoes below level 20 now. If this is correct, it means I can no longer get any more Training Guides.

Comment: There's probably another milestone that also earns you training guides, but I haven't gotten there yet.

Comment: Indeed, you get Training Codexes (Codices?) when your Palicoes reach level 35.